# how to provide unit values with mininclusive and maxinclusive values

Tags: xsd

I have one DTD

```
<parameter name="ReferenceSignalPower" access="readWrite">
  <syntax>
    <int>
      <range minInclusive="-60" maxInclusive="50" />
      <units value="dBm">
      </units>
    </int>
  </syntax>
</parameter>
```

I am new to XML schema i am not aware how to provide unit values with this XML schema

```
<xs:element name="ReferenceSignalPower">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:unsignedInt">
      <xs:minInclusive value="-60"/>
      <xs:maxInclusive value="50"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: ...put four spaces in front of code to format it (as I did)

Answer (score 2):

XML schemas do not have a concept of measurement units, you can define an XML attribute or XML element to contain numbers with certain restrictions (or other standard data-types like dates etc.), but it is the responsability of the application that reads the XML to interpret such numbers as values in a specific unit of measure.

If you want to add measurement unit information in the schema you can do it using the `appInfo` element - e.g.:

```
<xs:element name="ReferenceSignalPower">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <units value="dBm"/>
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
      <xs:minInclusive value="-60"/>
      <xs:maxInclusive value="50"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

but then you'll have to parse and interpret this information yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what your question is, but I suppose the question is "why does this not work?"

Your declaration is almost right, but not quite.  Why are you using unsignedInt as your base type, when you want a minimum value of -60?  The minimum value of unsignedInt is already set to zero.

The XSD spec assumes that if you attempt to set a minimum value to a value that's not part of the value space of your type, then there is an error somewhere.

So:  either use a signed integer type as your base type, or set the minimum value to a value that is actually present in the base type.